# AppServiceProvider boot function and Dynamic title

Tags: php, laravel, variables, laravel-blade

i passed variable to all views in AppServiceProvider boot()
i stored in this variable the name of the first user in the database
so i can put it in my layout as title

the problem happenes when there is no user in the database (new databases)
it through exception which says $title is not defind and that is true 
it is not defind so i tried to make if statment but it ignore it for some reason

boot ()

```
  public function boot()
    {
      Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

      View::composer('*',function($view){
        $title = DB::table('users')->first();
        $view->with('title',$title);
      });
```

i tried this as the logic but didn't work

```
 public function boot()
    {
      Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

      $check = DB::table('users')->first();
        if ($check != null) {
          View::composer('*',function($view){
            $title = DB::table('users')->first();
            $view->with('title',$title);  });
        }else {
          return view('nouser');
        }
```

there is no syntax error but i think the problem is every time the website reloads it renders all the layouts ( i have 3)
guest and admin have

```
<title>{{$title->name}}</title>
```

and app which the title is not dynamic in it and the nouser page i coded 
i extended the app layout bcs it doesn't have this variable which is undefined

the problem is i need to hide this exception from the user and redirect him to page that says please register and then i redirect him to the main pages after regiestration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by doing it in my pages controller insted of the appservice provider

pages controller

```
public function gethome()
  {
    $title = DB::table('users')->first();
      if ($title == null) {
        return redirect('/register');
      }else{
        $cvg = CV::all();
        return view('guest.cv')->with('cvg', $cvg);
  }
```

and did it for all the guest directories which they are 4 main routes

in AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
    {
      Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

      View::composer('*',function($view){
      $title = DB::table('users')->first();
      $view->with('title',$title);
  });
    }
```

in my guest layout

```
<title>{{$title->name}}</title>
```

hope this help anyone have the same problem Good luck and have fun coding

Answer (score 0):

The main problem on your code is; in case of there is no user you are trying to print something in the object. You should care **S.O.L.I.D.** principles when trying to implement something.

```
$countUsers = DB::table('users')->count();
$title = null;
if($countUsers > 0){
    $title = DB::table('users')->first()->name; 
}
View::composer('*',function($view){
    $view->with('title',$title);
});
if($countUsers == 0 ){
    return view('nouser');
}
```

and in your template use

```
<title>{{$title}}</title>
```

instead of

```
<title>{{$title->name}}</title>
```

Using `View::composer` is not a better solution to dynamically changing titles.
So, you can use [artesaos/seotools](https://github.com/artesaos/seotools) package for the dynamic titles, descriptions and much more easily. Also, it has got a dynamic twitter and opengraph meta generation feature which is really important for the seo.

```
<?php
....
class ForExampleController extends {
    public function viewUser($ID){
        $user = User::findOrFail($ID);
        SEO::setTitle($user->name);
        SEO::setDescription("This is the profile of ".$user->name);
        SEO::opengraph()->setUrl(...); // you can set users profile url
        // and much more..
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i replaced my code with yours first there is a syntax error the } that end the first case should be after the }); bcs if you put it like you said it says $title not defind second it didn't work after i  replaced my code i redirected to home ('/') and threw the same exception as the last time

Comment: i want to make declaration the main problem that i redirected to / the home page which uses guest layout which has the $title variable passed in and in this case it is not defined yet so i need to make if to check if it is not defined then return view no user and if it is defined then procced NOTE : i have more than 12 page which use the same guest layout thats why i put the logic in the boot function

Comment: Why you preferred hardest way? You can use default middleware's of Laravel

Comment: give me example if you can and i didn't use it because the guest interface should be available for everyone it is just one case that it should block access which is what i have explained above the middleware work for everyone and will block them all i mean it will work permenatly i just want a simple message to pop up ehen there is no user registered